# Jquery: Hide tooltip on form input focus if screen is smaller than

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that shows a simple tooltip in a form input focus. What I am trying to do is hide the tooltip div when the screen is smaller than 767px.

I already tried adding @media query display:none but that didn't work as when I resize the screen back to desktop size the tooltip div doesn't show back.

I tried this jQuery script but that didn't work either:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 767) {
       $('div.tip').hide();
    }
});
```

If I use `else { $('div.tip').show(); }` it shows all hidden tooltips on the page when I resize the screen back to desktop.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/5t19g403/)**

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should than inverse your CSS logic, and probably try adding some `!important`. Try for example mobile-first. No need to JS at all.

Comment: Also it's not clear why *` it shows all hidden tooltips on the page when I resize the screen back to desktop`* should be a problem.

Comment: It is a problem as the tooltips are supposed to be shown only on input focus state.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. I managed how to get this thing working. It was a simple matter of adding the whole script inside the else statement.

```
$('div.tip').hide();        

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
            $('div.tip').hide();
        } else {
            $('.display-tooltip').on('blur', function() {
            $(this).parent().siblings('div.tip').fadeOut(200);
        });

        $('.display-tooltip').on('focus', function() {
            $(this).parent().siblings('div.tip').fadeIn(200);
        });

        $(".display-tooltip").first().focus();
        }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/5t19g403/)

Answer (score -2):

You need to show the respective div in else condition, Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/5t19g403/7/),

```
// Hide tooltip if screen is smaller than 767
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 767) {
        $('div.tip').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('div.tip').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: **Avoid** doing intensive DOM traversal on resize. Cache your selectors instead. Also, OP should do that using CSS-only

Comment: If I use else { $('div.tip').show(); } it shows all hidden tooltips on the page when I resize the screen back to desktop.